# Need to prompt RDP file download in Chrome, FireFox

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, rdp

We have a RDP link on our website, which works great in IE (prompts download for the user as it should). However, if a user attempts to access the link in Chrome or FireFox, the file content is displayed instead of forcing download.

I've added proper content-type and content-disposition headers and also added the mime types within HTACCESS (AddType application/x-rdp rdp), but have had no luck forcing the download. Any suggestions?

Download link: http://www.drivecms.com/uploads/city-commercial.com/2100236394CityCom%20TS01.RDP

Comment: > _I've added proper content-type and content-disposition headers_
– 
it does not seem so, I do not get them. I get `text/plain` in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

An [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive somewhere in your web server’s configuration, or in the .htaccess file of a parent directory might prevent you from changing MIME types via htaccess files.

Comment: The override and also a double check on the headers did it. You all are great -Thank you!